# Wifi On/Off toggles 5 times per second!

Tags: wi-fi, 6.0-marshmallow, settings, oneplus-two

- Phone: OnePlus 2
- OS: Marshmallow 6.0 latest updates

When I go to the Android system wifi settings and click the slider to turn wifi off, the slider starts toggling back and forth very rapidly (4-5 times a second) and it seems to be almost impossible to stop it from doing so.  If I get lucky and hit the slider at just the right time it turns on the wifi again and seems to settle down.  This problem is easy to reproduce, and a reboot doesn't solve it.

Going into airplane mode turns off the wifi but coming out of airplane mode causes the toggling to resume.  This is a recent issue but I have not installed any apps lately nor changed any of the phone's settings so I wonder if it's a system update that has broken something.

When I am at home and connected to my home wifi this issue doesn't occur (as far as I've noticed).  When I am at work I usualy turn off wifi to save battery power and use LTE for data when I need it.  There are wifi networks available at work but I do not connect to them (I always remove the passwords to prevent accidental connections).

I can't find anyone else online who has had this exact issue.

What should I do to solve this?  Could this be an app-related issue?

Answer (score 0):

fixed it this way: Settings, location, improve accuracy and turn off wi-fi. So far problem seems to be fixed.

Answer (score 0):

I currently am using the same device OnePlus 2, on Android 6.0.

Here are some other threads that describe these symptoms that also have occured within the past week:

- https://productforums.google.com/forum/#!msg/android-wear/nunjJT1dGBU/2-XZea_5BgAJ
- http://forum.xda-developers.com/s7-edge/help/wifi-off-constantly-t3499683

This had started happening on the week at the earliest on the week of November 14th. I am experiencing the exact same symptoms you are describing. I hadn't changed any system settings that I believe would have caused this. **My hunch is that it is related to Google Play Services affecting version 10.84 (448-137749526)**. It is the only app that has all of these system wide permissions that updates in the background. I have turned off `Can modify system` settings and will see if this resolves the issue.